# How to create an product view tab with the images gallery in Magento 2.1?

Tags: product, magento-2.1, gallery

I'd like to add a new tab on the product view page to show the gallery of images inside this tab.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Complement your custom theme with this code below, so will show up a new tab with your image gallery with all features.

**File**

> app/design/frontend/[Package]/[theme]/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

**Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" name="product.gallery" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/gallery.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Gallery</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Result**

[image]